# YMIN must be a floating point scalar or a function handle

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make use of the `integral2` function in MATLAB for an integral:[image]

```
fun= @(x,y) (sin(x).*exp(-y.^2))/(y.^(2)+1*1+x.^4);
integral2(fun,8,1,2*x,-1);
```

but when I try to run it, I get an error:

> YMIN must be a floating point scalar or a function handle

What is wrong with my ymin value? and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `ymin` must be a floating point value or a function hanle, but in your case it doesn't seem to be either. converting it to a function handle works. (Also note that you need to use `./` instead of `/`.)

```
fun= @(x,y) (sin(x).*exp(-y.^2))./(y.^(2)+1*1+x.^4);
integral2(fun,8,1,@(x)2*x,-1);
```